# Correlation between first and third variable

Tags: correlation, pearson

Let's say we have correlation between x and y as `corr(x,y)` and correlation between y and z as `corr(y,z)`. What can be said of the correlation between x and z i.e. `corr(x,z)`?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: As this is not really programming related you might get a faster response at http://stats.stackexchange.com or http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can say much.

The correlation function is not even transitive - in other words if both `corr(x,y) > 0` and `corr(y,z) > 0`, you can't say if `corr(x,z) > 0`, `= 0` or `< 0`, unless those 2 correlations are especially high (`corr(x,y)`<sup>`2`</sup>`+ corr(y,z)`<sup>`2`</sup>`) > 1`)...

See for example this article: `ftp://163.25.117.117/gyliao/TODylan/Is%20the%20Property%20of%20Being%20Positively%20Correlated%20Transitive.pdf`

(for some reason I can't insert a clickable link)

Comment: Can you point to some useful read, specifically for what you said.

Comment: @nth see my edit. Now you could get more detailed answers on the math site as pointed out in the comments.